# How to add stroke in Ai Object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I created this drawing in AI. later to remove the plainness I took each one into Photoshop (Copy, and paste as pixel). done some coloring and merge all layers. later I place each one in Illustrator again (with a transparent background) to apply a black stroke. But no way I could apply that. I need a black stroke/boundary around each one.

Please tell me how can I do that. I want to stylize stroke. I cannot do that in PSD.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Photoshop has the Layer effects, including a Stroke. Isn't that one sufficient?

Comment: If you place a raster image in Illustrator, you can click the Mask button in the controls along the top, then choose a stroke colour.  This will only work for rectangles though, so it's not going to work for objects that have intricate details. Raster images have no strokes you can edit.

Comment: I want a grain brush stroke, as I can do in AI. How can in photoshop I make a stroke like that? @Vincent

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you.

Comment: Also, I don't really understand why you are using Photoshop at all in your workflow.  Best idea is to create everything in Illustrator if possible.  If you want to use raster textures made in Photoshop, you could use a clipping mask in Illustrator to clip them.

Comment: lol. I was told here 'create your artwork in Ai then modify that in photoshop' lol. now you said opposite, :D

and Billy , you can create strokes in pixel images also, using Appearance, I post same thing in Adobe Photoshop Forum, there One Expert showed me how can I do that in AI. @BillyKerr

Comment: Native Illustrator objects are vector, and vectors can have strokes and fills. But Photoshop images are raster. If you place a raster image in Illustrator, there is nothing in a raster image that Illustrator can stroke. You could of course create a vector object, and use it to clip the raster image, then you could apply a stroke to it (which is what the MASK button does). Or you could simply redraw an outline over the image, and apply a stroke to it.

Comment: Look, You know million times over than me about photoshop and Ai, I l dnt dare to say anything Because I treat you and rest as my teacher here, I learn from you guys, But in adobe, the forum Expert showed me to use appearance effects to create a stroke around my pixel object.  I learned your way too. I am the gainer. Thank you so much.

Comment: Um.. you dont want to go back and forh between photoshop and illustrator. Your going to lose something at each step. So either work everything in illustrator then go to PS and thats it your design is frozen. if you need to do changes you return to the original ai files do changes then redo the photoshop work. Or just bring in a roughness image into illustrator and use that to affect your illustrator objects and stay in illustrator.